# Back-end functionality for a file sharing website

Tags: php, file-upload, dropbox, cloud-storage

How file uploads to a clustered environment are typically handled using PHP?

I am currently working on a backend system for a cloud storage/sharing website

I would like to make sure that a clients upload is stored to the node with least load and most available resources, creating a unique file reference stored to the database. Also multiple uploads of the same file should be detected to reduce space.

Are there any best practices, design patterns documentation covering this topic and might help illustrating what is needed to get things done here.

Comment: any service (like any amazon cloud services) will have samples for interacting with their API. Integration scripts are typically available but will require some skill to implement. As for the rest, what have you tried? We're here to help with code, not code for you. By your description simply installing wordpress gets you 70% of the way there.

Comment: Wordpress and i am even 99% ON the way to get shattered.

Comment: "Typically" handled? You're asking "Please tell me in a short answer textbox everything about how to build and run a service that can compete with DropBox/Amazon S3/etc. at their core business model".

Comment: I have no idea what your comment means, romu. but to back heckler - a full scale enterprise system is serious business. But if you want what you describe - there's no reason why wordpress wouldn't be able to handle it for some small service that should consider full scale when the user base justifies the expense.

Comment: Thanks for your kind feedback so far, appreciate it. Well i am really not that experienced back-end developer. I am more into front-end website/application design. However, my budget right now is quiet low, about 10-15k and i don´t think i will find a engineer here could hit me up with a full scale enterprise cloud storage/sharing service for that. Also i would like to learn and grow and now just looking for a starting point. I´ve done a lot of websites with Wordpress but i don´t think its the right approach here. What about PHP/MVC and the Yii Framework ?